# Perl successful alternation match

Tags: regex, perl

I was using Regex to match ISO8601 style date/time or date using the following:-

```
my $regexdate = qr/((?:19|20)[[:digit:]]{2})[-]?([[:digit:]]{2})[-]?([[:digit:]]{2})/;
my $regextime = qr/([[:digit:]]{2})[:]?([[:digit:]]{2})[:]?([[:digit:]]{2})/;
my $datime = qr/(?:$regexdate[ T]?$regextime)|$regexdate/;
```

I though it would be easier if I used the result of the match in list context so tried:-

```
my @result =  ($file =~ m/$datime/p);
```

When I tried to print I got a number of `uninitialized value` warnings, indicating that the list contained 9 elements rather than the 6 or 3 I was expecting.

```
print "$file\t=> ${^MATCH}\t@result\n";
```

I was expecting only the successful alternation match to return values, by my reading of the documentation is obviously not what `Perl` actually does.

Is there any simple way of returning the successful alternation, or do I need to try another approach.

Comment: Which part of the documentation are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final pattern

```
qr/(?:$regexdate[ T]?$regextime)|$regexdate/
```

has nine captures: three in `$regexdate`, three in `$regextime` and three more in the second copy of `$regexdate`

While you *could* use the "branch reset" construct, like this

```
qr/(?|$regexdate[ T]$regextime|$regexdate)/
```

it would make more sense to simply make the time field optional, like so

```
qr/$regexdate(?:[ T]$regextime)?/
```

***Note*** *that I have removed the quantifier from the space/T that separates the date from the time as it is non-optional in ISO8601. I also don't understand why you have made the date and time field separators `[-]` and `[:]` optional in the constituent regexes. That is also wrong for ISO8601.*

Comment: This has helped my understanding of Perl regex and for the moment I am using optional time, but will explore further. Everyone wants to change my `ISO 8601`.  `[-]` and `[:]` are optional in basic format (I don't have a copy of `ISO 8601` since retiring). It was never my intention to strictly follow `ISO 8601` but the "style" and work with the common variants including `[_]` and `[.]` and missing time separator.

Comment: @Milliways: [ISO 8601](http://www.uai.cl/images/sitio/biblioteca/citas/ISO_8601_2004en.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `(?|...)` construct.

Capture groups have continuous numbering spanning even across alternation and the `(?|...)` construct has been introduced to address this. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Alternative-capture-group-numbering for details.

So with this minor but significant change your code may look like this: https://ideone.com/ux3Ndz.

There is another way around this problem in your particular case. Instead of using alternation (i.e. `$date[ T]$time|$date`) you may make the date part optional (`$date(?:[ T]$time)?`) thus eliminating the alternation group numbering issue. [Here](https://ideone.com/gcPL7G)'s an example. I also changed Posix classes to Perl ones and removed unnecessary char class brackets (`[...]`) to make the code more concise.